# Toggle class is not stable for table's cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, toggleclass, ngtable

I am using toggle class for highlighting table cells.

```
<style>
           table td.highlighted {
            background-color: #999;
        }
</style>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var isMouseDown = false;

        $("#productTable td")
          .mousedown(function () {

              isMouseDown = true;
                debugger;

                  $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");

              return false; // prevent text selection
          });

        $(document)
          .mouseup(function () {
                debugger;
              isMouseDown = false;
          });
    });
</script>
```

And my table is like this:

```
 <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Aramak İstediğiniz Ürün Alanını Giriniz" ng-model="src_product">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <br />
                            <table ng-table="usersTable" id="productTable" class="table table-striped">

                                <tr>
                                    <th ng-repeat="column in cols">{{column}}</th>
                                    <th> Adet</th>
                                </tr>

                                <tr ng-repeat="row in data  | filter: src_product">
                                    <td id="productProperties" ng-model="productProperties"  ng-repeat="column in cols ">{{row[column]}}</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 30px !important" name=" adet" value="0"></td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

this is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('productController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'SharedDataService', "productFactory", "$log", "$filter", 'ngTableParams', function ($rootScope, $scope, SharedDataService, productFactory, $log, $filter, ngTableParams) {


    $scope.users = [{"id":1,"first_name":"Philip","last_name":"Kim","email":"pkim0@mediafire.com","country":"Indonesia","ip_address":"29.107.35.8"},
                        {"id":2,"first_name":"Judith","last_name":"Austin","email":"jaustin1@mapquest.com","country":"China","ip_address":"173.65.94.30"},
                        {"id":3,"first_name":"Julie","last_name":"Wells","email":"jwells2@illinois.edu","country":"Finland","ip_address":"9.100.80.145"},
                        {"id":4,"first_name":"Gloria","last_name":"Greene","email":"ggreene3@blogs.com","country":"Indonesia","ip_address":"69.115.85.157"},                      
    {"id":50,"first_name":"Andrea","last_name":"Greene","email":"agreene4@fda.gov","country":"Russia","ip_address":"128.72.13.52"},{"id":1,"first_name":"Philip","last_name":"Kim","email":"pkim0@mediafire.com","country":"Indonesia","ip_address":"29.107.35.8"},
                        {"id":2,"first_name":"Judith","last_name":"Austin","email":"jaustin1@mapquest.com","country":"China","ip_address":"173.65.94.30"},
                        {"id":3,"first_name":"Julie","last_name":"Wells","email":"jwells2@illinois.edu","country":"Finland","ip_address":"9.100.80.145"},
                        {"id":4,"first_name":"Gloria","last_name":"Greene","email":"ggreene3@blogs.com","country":"Indonesia","ip_address":"69.115.85.157"},                      
    { "id": 50, "first_name": "Andrea", "last_name": "Greene", "email": "agreene4@fda.gov", "country": "Russia", "ip_address": "128.72.13.52" },
    { "id": 1, "first_name": "Philip", "last_name": "Kim", "email": "pkim0@mediafire.com", "country": "Indonesia", "ip_address": "29.107.35.8" },
                        { "id": 2, "first_name": "Judith", "last_name": "Austin", "email": "jaustin1@mapquest.com", "country": "China", "ip_address": "173.65.94.30" },
                        { "id": 3, "first_name": "Julie", "last_name": "Wells", "email": "jwells2@illinois.edu", "country": "Finland", "ip_address": "9.100.80.145" },
                        { "id": 4, "first_name": "Gloria", "last_name": "Greene", "email": "ggreene3@blogs.com", "country": "Indonesia", "ip_address": "69.115.85.157" },
    { "id": 50, "first_name": "Andrea", "last_name": "Greene", "email": "agreene4@fda.gov", "country": "Russia", "ip_address": "128.72.13.52" }];


    $scope.usersTable = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 10
    }, {
        total: $scope.users.length,
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.users, params.orderBy()) : $scope.users;
            $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;
            $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            $defer.resolve($scope.data);
        }
    });
    $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.users[0]);

    $scope.idSelectedVote = null;
    $scope.setSelected = function (idSelectedVote) {
        debugger;
        $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
    };
    $scope.src_product = '';
}]);
```

My table is looking like this:

[image]

Here is the my  question. when i search a word or go second page of table highlighted cells are turn back non highligted and it doesnt let me select a cell. How can i do stable cells and take highlighted cells values ?

Comment: If your rows are removed on the change of the page, the only way you can achieve this is by creating your own store of selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

On page change or search, the table is redrawn so your class change is lost. If you assign the class based on a model value, you could instead change the model value and get the class modified, and this would be persisted across redraws. You can use ng-class attribute to make the class name used for the td dependant on a model value. For example:

```
<td ng-class="{'highlighted':row[column].isSelected}" ng-click="selectCell(row[column])"></td>
```

Then, inside your controller, you can create a function:

```
$scope.selectCell = function(cell) { 
    typeof cell.isSelected === "undefined" ? cell.isSelected = true : cell.isSelected = false;
}
```

[ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)
[ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Comment: I tried this but  cell.isSelected is always undefined, never change. How can i set true value as initial isSelected ?

Comment: Could you recreate the issue on code pen please? It'll be easier to resolve:
http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: I added just necessary parts but its not working now :S What am i missing ?

Comment: I'm going to create a working sample and see if I can solve it locally. But, I'll do that when I have time within the next week so hopefully someone else may answer earlier.